# (Possible bug) Issue in next tag badge progress bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

I am seeing my next tag badge progress bar incomplete.

[image: No counts]

There is no count in `xxx/xxx` format. Is this a bug?

Running on Chrome version 42, Windows 7.

---

P.S - If it matters, this seems to be an issue with *all* the stats.

[image]

Comment: Also reported here: [Badge progress indicator missing score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257020/262755)

Comment: I have never seen that page.  where is it at?

Comment: @NathanOliver which page?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Where it is showing your tag badge progress.

Comment: @NathanOliver aah, the last screenshot, is it? Just click on the "wheel" icon on the left hand side of the "Next tag badge" area. (_Choose which tag batch to track_).

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am doing a miseable job explaning myself.  where is the `"Next tag badge" area` located at.  I can't find that on my profile page.

Comment: @NathanOliver what? is it? Try "Activity" tab, "Reputation" block....got it?

Comment: @NathanOliver see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver?tab=topactivity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be fixed (or is about to be).

From [this answer at Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257032/262755):

> This was my bad when fixing some localization issues.
>
> A fix will be pushed out shortly.

Comment: yep. thanks for sharing the info. :)