# (Possible bug) Next tag badge: score isn't changed

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I've found this ticket: [(Possible bug) Issue in next tag badge progress bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295042/possible-bug-issue-in-next-tag-badge-progress-bar), but it seems it wasn't fully fixed till now.

What I've noticed: `score` in next tag badge doesn't change its value (while `answers` progress does). Workaround is select this tag badge ones again - score becomes actual.

[image]

**UPDATE** Here is screenshot of selecting next tag badge window, where you can notice that real score and answers number differ from shown in profile:

[image]

Comment: Workaround, select a tag to track, select the same tag you were previously tracking. It will update.

Comment: @Ferrybig it is just what I said in the question. You didn't provide me any useful information